# Filter Dataset Result based on Parameter Value

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2008, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I am working on Microsoft Dynamics Reporting service. My requirement is to show records which is dated 3 years or earlier from a given date. The parameter I have is a date selection field. What I am trying to achieve is get records based on my condition from the date I have selected on the parameter.

To filter data based on the current date, I can use:

```
<condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="olderthan-x-months" value="36" />
```

But, to get the data filtered based on the parameter value is what  I can't figure out.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a dynamic date for the report. We can add another date which will have a custom code to have a date 3 years prior to the input date or current date. This date can be referenced to the FetchXML query to filter the records.

Answer (score 0):

You should use between operator, but in fetchxml you can achieve it this way.

```
<filter type="and">
  <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" value="2016-10-04" />
  <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-before" value="2019-10-03" />
</filter>
```

Also expression can help you to calculate and pass parameters.

Comment: Hey Arun, Thank you for the answer.  I guess I communicated wrong. I wanted 3 years or earlier. Also, you have a fixed date. What I wanted is a dynamics date. The date should be picked from the parameter which is entered by the user.

Comment: @Harsha research using keywords in my answer last line: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/no-audience/2011/03/18/parameterizing-fetch-based-reports/

Comment: Hey Arun, sorry for the late reply. This was fixed by passing an external date input and referencing another date which was exactly 3 years prior to the input value as the value of the filter condition.